# What is the probability that the distance between $a$ and $b$ is greater than $2$ when $-2 \leq a \leq 1$ and $0 \leq b \leq 2$?

Tags: probability

Two points $a$ and $b$ are randomly selected such that $-2 \leq a \leq 1$ and $0 \leq b \leq 2$.

Find the probability that the distance between $a$ and $b$ is greater than $2$.

(Answer: $\frac{1}{3}$)

I'm getting $\frac{1}{4}$

Am I wrong or is the solution wrong.

I plotted it on a system of 2 axes. One with $a$ and the other with $b$.

I drew a dotted linear line from $(-2, 0)$ to $(0,2)$. I saw 3 of the 12 points being greater than having a distance of 2. Are there more?

Comment: $a$ and $b$ are real numbers in the respective ranges, not (necessarily) integers. There are infinitely many points to consider.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have done, draw a rectangle (whose area is $6$) of the given domain in the $ab$-plane. The desired region we want is when $|a - b| > 2$ so that either $b > a + 2$ or $b < a - 2$. Only the first inequality is relevant here; shade in the part of the rectangle that satisfies it. You'll get a triangle whose area is $2$, which explains why the answer is:
$$
\frac{2}{6} = \frac{1}{3}
$$

Comment: Oh I see. It makes sense if you use area to include all real points. Thanks